# SQL Union query simplification

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I don't know if this question is apropriate on this forum.

I have a huge query :

```
SELECT threshold.id, brand.id, COUNT(brand.id), threshold
FROM current_stock, article, product, brand, delivery, threshold
    WHERE current_stock.article_id = article.id
    AND article.product_product_code = product.product_code
    AND product.brand_id = brand.id
    AND article.delivery_id = delivery.id
    AND delivery.store_id = 'E260'
    AND threshold.brand_id = brand.id
    GROUP BY brand.id
    HAVING COUNT(brand.id) <= threshold
UNION
SELECT threshold.id, brand.id, 0, threshold
FROM current_stock, article, product, brand, delivery, threshold
    WHERE threshold.store_id = 'E260'
    AND threshold.brand_id NOT IN (
        SELECT brand_id FROM current_stock, article, product, delivery
        WHERE current_stock.article_id = article.id
        AND article.product_product_code = product.product_code
        AND article.delivery_id = delivery.id
        AND delivery.store_id = 'E260')
```

And I think it's possible to do better but after a entire day of try I haven't found a better query giving the same result.

For clarify, I have a stock (with current_stock, article, product and delivery). I also have thresholds. what I want is to check for each thresholds if there is the given minimum amount of stock for the given brand.

My problem is that if there is 0 article of a brand, the first part of the query will not take care about the threshold on this brand. It's why I have added an uggly Union.

Someone have an idea for a better way to do this ?

---

## EDIT

This what I have done after the reading of comments and answers :

SELECT t.id, b.id, t.threshold, count(b.id) stock

```
FROM threshold t
    inner join brand b on b.id = t.brand_id 
    left join product p on p.brand_id = b.id 
    inner join article a on a.product_product_code = p.product_code 
    inner join delivery d on d.id = a.delivery_id 
    inner join current_stock cs on cs.article_id = a.id

WHERE
    t.store_id = 'E260' AND
    d.store_id = 'E260'

GROUP BY b.id
HAVING stock <= t.threshold
```

My problem is that it don't gives all threholds... only ones that have at least one 'current_stock'. I have perhaps don't understand how joins are working.

Here an example of threshold table :

```
| id | brand_id | threshold |
-----------------------------
| 1  |   86     |     1     |
| 2  |   28     |     1     |
| 3  |   12     |     1     |
```

What I want as result this :

```
# with 2 entries in 'current_stock' for the brand id 28, 1 for 12 and 0 for 86

| t.id | b.id | threshold | stock |
-----------------------------------
|  1   |  86  |    1      |   0   |
|  3   |  12  |    1      |   1   |
```

Comment: You should start by rewriting the queries using proper explicit `join` syntax and table aliases.  That is one way to help other people understand your query.

Comment: @Gordon ok i will edit soon

Comment: If you want to include brands with no articles, use a `LEFT JOIN` with `article`.

Comment: I have edited with joins but it doesn't work as expected

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing a few parts here since you've used implicit joins in your sample. An explicit version would look something like this (provided I guessed correctly for how you are joining the threshold table).

```
SELECT
t.id,
b.id,
COUNT(b.id),
t.threshold

FROM
current_stock c
inner join article a on a.id = c.article_id
inner join delivery d on d.id = a.delivery_id
inner join product p on p.product_code = a.product_product_code
inner join brand b on b.id = p.brand_id
inner join threshold t on t.brand_id = b.id

WHERE
d.store_id = 'E260'

GROUP BY b.id
HAVING COUNT(b.id) <= t.threshold
```

Now to get your results to include rows where there aren't any 'articles' you can start switching out the inner joins for left joins. However, you can't simply use `left outer join article...` in the example above, because the `store_id` in the `WHERE` clause will just turn it back into a pseudo inner join.

Instead, is there a different field you can join the `delivery` table on from `current_stock`?

**EDIT - 07/29/15**

I think you're close, you may just have one too many filters and you're counting from 'b' when the wanted outcome suggests you should be counting from 'cs' instead. Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, b.id, t.threshold, count(cs.id) stock

FROM
threshold t
inner join brand b on b.id = t.brand_id
inner join product p on p.brand_id = b.id
inner join article a on a.product_product_code = p.product_code
left outer join delivery d on d.store_id = t.store_id
left outer join current_stock cs on cs.article_id = a.id

WHERE
t.store_id = 'E260'

GROUP BY b.id
HAVING stock <= t.threshold
```

Comment: What is thé différence between using join statement and using Where clause like in m'y question ?

Comment: The query optimizer should end up doing to same thing for both ways of writing it, but for human readability explicit join syntax is currently winning (implicit joins are deprecated in newer versions of RDBMS).

Comment: And what will happend for values that are not filled ? For exemple, if there is no article of a brand, what will be thé value of COUNT(brand.id) ?

Comment: I have edited my question with a better looking but not actualy working query

Comment: I added another query, let me know if that gets you any closer to the outcome you're looking for.

Comment: The solution i have found is to make à deriveded table for product in stock informations